# Use Induction to prove the following generalisation of the triangle inequality:

Tags: real-analysis

If $n \geq 2$ is a natural number and $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are real numbers, then
$|a_1 + \cdots + a_n| \leq |a_1|+ \cdots + |a_n|$.

I'm stuck on where to start and what direction to go with this question? Any help would be useful thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $|a_1+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1}|\leq |a_1|+\dots +|a_{n+1}|$. Using induction we have that $|a_1+\dots+a_n+|\leq |a_1|+\dots + |a_n|$, hence we get 
$$
|a_1+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1}|\leq |a_1 +\dots +a_n| + |a_{n+1}| \leq |a_1|+\dots +|a_{n+1}|
$$
where the first inequality holds considering $a_1 +\dots +a_n$ as a single number (therefore induction again gives you the inequality).

Answer (score 0):

So we have the base case $n=2$ $|a_1+a_2| \leq |a_1|+|a_2|$. So assume the $n$th case holds. That is,

$$|a_1+\dots a_n| \leq |a_1| + \dots + |a_n|$$

and consider

$$|a_1+ \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}| \leq |a_1+ \dots + a_n| + |a_{n+1}|$$

and now the result follows by induction.